# create a folder using last id in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a folder from my last ID.

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
mkdir($id, 0777, true);
```

it is not working. how can I create a folder with last ID?

Comment: Do you get an error? Is `$id` set?

Comment: it's creating 0 folder. always 0

Comment: That doesnt answer either question.

Comment: I didn't get any error.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","green");
            $id=mysqli_insert_id($con);
            mkdir($id, 0777, true); it's my code

Comment: `$id` is set? You are monitoring your error log? The code in the question and the last comment dont match.

Comment: yes. `$id` is set. I am monitoring. there is no any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the connection parameter to the method :

> **$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");**
>
> **$id=mysqli_insert_id($con);**

In addiction, the mkdir method takes as first parameter the path of the folder : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: but it is creating 0 folder